# Using t-sql to run a query using a column from the same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a ASPX website driven by SQL Server. One of the functions of the website is to run some reports on the backend database and spit the results out to the user. I am not really familiar with the whole ASPX stuff so this may be really obvious.

Each individual who logs in to the website has a `site` attribute (e.g. where they are) and they can run reports for their `site`. The SQL for each of the reports are stored as text in a column in the `Reports` table that also has a `site` column.

The person who wrote the previous SQL reports hard coded `site=#` in the text of each of the queries so right now he has a bunch of rows with essentially the same query with the difference being `WHERE site=1`, `WHERE site=2` etc...  That seems like it will be a pain to manage if the number of sites is large.

Is there a more efficient way of limiting the query rather than putting in my `WHERE` statement `pt.siteID=4` in the queries ?

I want to have some sort of self join but I cannot seem to figure out the syntax.

```
DECLARE @myReports TABLE (ReportName varchar(max),
                          siteID int)

INSERT INTO @myReports
VALUES( 'SELECT pt.siteID, pt.patientID, endDate AS EndDate
         FROM Patient pt 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN 
              (SELECT DISTINCT patientID FROM MedicationSchedule) sm ON pt.patientID = sm.patientID
         WHERE mode = 1 AND sm.patientID IS NULL AND pt.siteID = 2', 2)

INSERT INTO @myReports
VALUES('SELECT pt.siteID, pt.patientID, endDate AS EndDate
        FROM Patient pt 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            (SELECT DISTINCT patientID FROM MedicationSchedule) sm ON pt.patientID = sm.patientID
        WHERE mode = 1 AND sm.patientID IS NULL AND pt.siteID = 3', 3)

INSERT INTO @myReports
VALUES('SELECT pt.siteID, pt.patientID, endDate AS EndDate
        FROM Patient pt 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            (SELECT DISTINCT patientID FROM MedicationSchedule) sm ON pt.patientID = sm.patientID
        WHERE mode = 1 AND sm.patientID IS NULL AND pt.siteID = 4', 4)

SELECT * from @myReports
```

Comment: The whole architecture here seems to be very off. This would be a lot simpler if the code was not stored in the database. As a stored procedure this would be a zillion times simpler. You pass in the SiteID as a parameter to the procedure and you don't need to store this at all.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not my site so I cannot change *everything* about it and make it even a scintilla simpler, rather than a zillion!  I'll check about the stored procedure but in the meantime, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of this as a procedure instead stored in a table that you then have to execute.

```
create procedure ProcedureNameHere
(
    @SiteID int --or whatever datatype is appropriate
) as

    set nocount on;

    SELECT pt.siteID
        , pt.patientID
        , pt.endDate AS EndDate
    FROM Patient pt 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ms.patientID 
        FROM MedicationSchedule ms
    ) sm ON pt.patientID = sm.patientID
    WHERE mode = 1 --not sure what table this is from, would be best to add the alias
        AND sm.patientID IS NULL 
        AND pt.siteID = @SiteID;
```

Then you just pass the appropriate value for SiteID to get the appropriate data.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat of a hack but this does it within my constraints:

```
DECLARE @myReports TABLE 
(ReportText varchar(max),
 ReportName varchar(max),
 siteID int
)

DECLARE @sites varchar(max)
SET @sites = '2,3,4,'

DECLARE @pos INT
DECLARE @len INT
set @pos = 0
set @len = 0

DECLARE @value varchar(8000)


DECLARE @mySQL varchar(max)
SET @mySQL ='SELECT pt.siteID, pt.patientID, endDate AS EndDate
           FROM Patient pt LEFT OUTER JOIN 
           (SELECT DISTINCT patientID FROM MedicationSchedule) sm ON pt.patientID=sm.patientID
         WHERE 
         mode=1 AND sm.patientID IS NULL AND 
         pt.siteID='

WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @sites, @pos+1)>0
BEGIN
    set @len = CHARINDEX(',', @sites, @pos+1) - @pos
    set @value = SUBSTRING(@sites, @pos, @len)
    --SELECT @pos, @len, @value /*this is here for debugging*/

    INSERT INTO @myReports
        SELECT @mySQL+@value AS ReportText,
        'Find No Schedules', @value  

    set @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @sites, @pos+@len) +1
END


SELECT * FROM @myReports
```